# OpenGL glDeleteTextures C/C++

Tags: c++, opengl, memory, overflow

I'm working with a 2D game that has multiple levels that can be loaded and (and should be unloaded.)

To make it easier to handle textures I wrote a TextureLoader class that has a list with all the textures, when an object in the game wants to use a texture it only has the path to the texture it wishes to use and then asks the TextureLoader if it can obtain a pointer to the texture with the same path. Then if the texture doesn't exist in the list the TextureLoader will attempt to load it before sending back the pointer.

This works fine throughout the game and when I reload a level the memory usage stays the same.

But when I load a new level I obviously want the previous level to be unloaded, however it doesn't seem to work.

That's where glDeleteTextures come in.

So what I try to do is:

```
int arraySize = textures.size();
GLuint* arr = new GLuint[arraySize];
int x = 0;
for (std::list<Texture2D*>::iterator it = textures.begin(); it != textures.end(); ++it)
{
    arr[x] = (*it)->getImage();
    x++;
}
glDeleteTextures(arraySize, arr);

textures.clear();
```

Since the pointers to the memory are stored in a seperate Texture2D class I attempt to collect all of them before calling glDeleteTextures;

However my memory usage keeps growing for every level until I reach a stack overflow.

```
 getImage()
```

returns a GLuint with a pointer to the texture that I obtain when I first bound the texture.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you created all the texture IDs individually, I don't think the array delete will work - however I might be wrong here. Also, make sure that the textures are unbound when calling delete. Bound textures will not release.

Comment: as for the stack overflow you are getting, maybe post a callstack.

Comment: I'm not sure how to unbind textures, I tried glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) but it didn't help. If I can't delete individually deleted IDs, how can I work around that?

Answer (score 1):

You are not incrementing 'x'.

Additionally you leak the memory of the array.  Why not use a vector?

```
std::vector<GLuint> arr;
arr.reserve(textures.size());
for (std::list<Texture2D*>::iterator it = textures.begin(); it != textures.end(); ++it)
{
    arr.push_back((*it)->getImage());

    // Are you missing:
    // delete *it;
}
if (!arr.empty()) {
    glDeleteTextures(arr.size(), &arr[0]);
}
textures.clear();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid the not incrementing x was just a typo.
I tried your solution as well and it didn't work, perhaps getImage() doesn't return the correct path to the memory?

Comment: Maybe add some debug code to verify the texture ID's that were created and the ID's that you are destroying.

Comment: The id is the pointer to the memory, right? So as long as I can use the image in the game it should be the correct value. However, does it have to be constant as glDeleteTexture asks for const values?

Comment: @Orujimaru: No, texture IDs are not pointers. You obviously thought so, also from reading your original questiones. OpenGL object names/IDs are just numbers, i.e. numeric handles. And they don't act like pointers.

Comment: just try debug tracing the value(s) you get from glGenTextures and the value(s) that you pass to glDeleteTextures and verify if all the values you got from glGenTextures are passed to glDeleteTextures correctly.

Comment: Additionally what are you doing with the Texture2D pointers? Since you had a typo in your code you posted, I can assume that it is not the same code that you are actually running?

Comment: Thanks I'll try that, I delete the the pointers. Just like in your example.

Answer (score 0):

After monitoring my VRam usage I can see that the Vram is being freed properly, so the issue is because OpenGL stores copies in the system RAM that don't get freed up when I call glDeleteTextures().